# Batch FOR loop without setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Tags: batch-file

using this code for example :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set  arrayline[0]=############
set  arrayline[1]=#..........#
set  arrayline[2]=#..........#
set  arrayline[3]=#..........#
set  arrayline[4]=#..........#
set  arrayline[5]=#..........#
set  arrayline[6]=#..........#
set  arrayline[7]=#..........#
set  arrayline[8]=#..........#
set  arrayline[9]=#..........#
set arrayline[10]=#..........#
set arrayline[11]=#..........#
set arrayline[12]=############

::read it using a FOR /L statement
for /l %%n in (0,1,12) do (
echo !arrayline[%%n]!
)
pause
```

I want to use "normal" variable syntax instead of using setlocal enabledelayedexpansion (line 1).

I mean that instead of `!arrayline[%%n]!` I want to have something like that : `%arrayline[n]%` in order to put the information in it, in a variable (this way:)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set  arrayline[0]=############
set  arrayline[1]=#..........#
set  arrayline[2]=#..........#
set  arrayline[3]=#..........#
set  arrayline[4]=#..........#
set  arrayline[5]=#..........#
set  arrayline[6]=#..........#
set  arrayline[7]=#..........#
set  arrayline[8]=#..........#
set  arrayline[9]=#..........#
set arrayline[10]=#..........#
set arrayline[11]=#..........#
set arrayline[12]=############

::read it using a FOR /L statement
for /l %%n in (0,1,12) do (
set buffer=%arrayline[n]%
echo %buffer%
)
pause
```

I **NEED** to put the information in a variable (which is buffer here).

If possible, can somebody replace the necessary code in mine ?

I'm a begginer so if it is not clear enough just ask ;)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using setlocal enabledelayedexpansion?

Comment: There is seldom a good reason to use percent expansion in a four loop. I suppose you misunderstand some points about delayed expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CALL echo %%arrayline[%%n]%%
```

is the classic solution here. This executes `echo %arrayline[n]%` in a subprocedure.

---

```
CALL SET "myvar=%%arrayline[%%n]%%"
CALL ECHO %%myvar%%
```

Comment: I actually want to put !arrayline[%%n]! in a variable but i can't with that syntax. yours doesn't allow to put the information in a variable too so ...